# Implement ad network custom tags in Android application

Tags: events, tags, admob

I would like to serve ads in an Android application though AdMob mediation from a third party network. This particular ad network is not listed under the AdMob mediation networks. Is there a way to do this? They have provided me with a tag that is basically a small piece of javascript code. Could this be done using AdMob custom events? If so, is there an example on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, custom events can be used to support your requirements.
See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/custom-events
And https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/tree/master/mediation_adapter/src/com/google/ads/mediation/sample/customevent

Essentially when the CustomEvent is called you need to populate a View with the ad from the 3rd party network using whatever mechanic they provide you with.